# is there a way to exit the modeless vi without closing the window?

Tags: linux, vim, terminal, vi

As being a beginner, I started learning some new command options  about vim and while trying the **Modeless vi** by typing the command `vim -y [name of the file to edit]` I didn't found a way to come back to the terminal but closing it.

I know that the command above run `vim` in insert mode without permiting the command mode but my question is there any way to exit vi while staying in the same terminal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CTRL-L` puts vim back into normal mode.
Then `:q` to quit or `:q!` to quit without saving.

Answer (score 1):

Vim's "easy mode" is a very different beast than regular Vim/Vi. Easy mode goes out of it's way to try and make Vim modeless which is heresy as far as I am concerned.

If you do want to learn some Vim commands then I suggest you take 20 minutes or so and run `vimtutor`. It will teach you the some basic Vim commands. I would also suggest making a cheat sheet if you are having a hard time remembering the commands or go through `vimtutor` again. As always the Vim documentation is there via `:h`.

Comment: Thank you but actually, I know the basics of the vim that anyone must know I also started to make and create my own .exrc file in order to program faster. The problem while surfing I come across this option -y  so I just wanted to test it.  I can agee that the eady mode is much more better than the modelss mode .  You maybe misunderstood the word beginner but your comment is really precious !